# Add 2 array values into one vector c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have 2 arrays called movePositionsX and movePositionY like so

```
int movePositionsX[5] = { 1080 , 720 , 160 , 240 , 640};
int movePositionsY[5] = { 720 , 360 , 520, 860 , 164};
```

I have a random to get one of the random positions on both of the arrays and i want to put them both into 1 vector2 how can i do so?

This is the vector2

```
vector<int> combine;
```

I have this code till now but it gives out an error 'no matching function call to std::vector::insert(, int&, int&, float&)'

```
circleObjectArray[i].setPosition(Interpolate(circleObjectArray[i].getPosition(),combine.insert(combine.end,movePositionsX[rand() % 5], movePositionsY[rand() % 5], factor));
```

This is my interpolate function

```
Vector2f Interpolate(
const Vector2f pointA,
const Vector2f pointB,
float factor
) {
if( factor > 1.f )
    factor = 1.f;

else if( factor < 0.f )
    factor = 0.f;

return pointA + (pointB - pointA) * factor;
}
```

How can i combine both values of the arrays into 1 vector2 to use it in this function?

Thank you for your time :D

Comment: What does vector::insert() return

Comment: This has nothing to do with SFML.

Comment: Looks like you have your ) in the wrong place

Comment: @drescherjm oh my god idk how i missed that :( i fixed it and now it gives out this error 'no matching function for call to std::vector<int>::insert(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int&, int&)

Comment: @JesperJuhl im sorry im going to remove the tag and sfml from the title

Comment: I think you probably want to do the combine.insert before this line. I think a push_back() is probably what you want.

Comment: `combine.end` is not an iterator pointing to the last item its a pointer to function. You forgot the () after the end meaning you wanted combine.end()

Comment: thank you so much it worked with the push_back() :D
now i just need to find out how to convert vector<int> to a vector2f

Comment: are you trying to create a new vector by summing the ith values of both, or do you want a new vector which would be a series of vectors that are (A, B) coordinates?

Comment: im trying to create a new vector that are (A,B) coordinates